# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libusb-1.0.so

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-auto

I upgrade my Android Studio, Gradle and compileSdkVersion.

Suddenly, I can not open  Android Auto Desktop Head Unit Emulator.
I don't understand the error message about the path "@rpath/libusb-1.0.so"?! not loaded?

The error message

```
MacBook-Pro:auto xxxx$ /Users/xxxx/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb forward tcp:5277 tcp:5277
5277
MacBook-Pro:auto xxxx $ ./desktop-head-unit
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libusb-1.0.so
  Referenced from: /Users/xxxx/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/auto/./desktop-head-unit
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
        /Users/xxxx/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/auto/libusb-1.0.so: cannot load 'libusb-1.0.so' (load command 0x80000034 is unknown)
Abort trap: 6
```

The system settings
[image]

Comment: `libusb` is a library that is now included when you download the Desktop Head Unit and should be in the same folder as the `desktop-head-unit` executable (to support connecting over the Android Accessory protocol instead of ADB). It might be easiest to uninstall (by unselecting the DHU in the SDK Tools list in your screenshot and clicking *Apply*) and then re-install the DHU. See https://developer.android.com/training/cars/testing#install for more details.

Comment: @BenSagmoe I've checked and tried what you mentioned. 1) Make sure  `desktop-head-unit` and `libusb-1.0.so` are under the same folder `...\Android\sdk\extras\google\auto` 2)Reinstall DHU, I even reinstall AS. But it still not works.